# Squirrel 4.0.0, error at the opening of the session

Tags: session, squirrel

I'm working since few days on a new PC on windows 10. I have just install first, Java version 1.8 and second, Squirrel version 4.0.0 via Java on windows cmd. I have created all the alias needed, and I have tested the connection => OK
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46CS3.png)

However, when I launch the connection thanks to the recently created alias, I have a message "Error when opening the session". I'm not a computer specialist, and I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5K9c.png)

I have never had such problem in former days with my old PC and my old Squirrel version. Could you help me, please ? For instance, with some other requesters I have no problem at all (Beaver, or with ODBC links, WINSQL, MSQUERY or HEIDI), but I prefer and I'm more used to Squirrel.

Comment: Excuse me for the mistakes, "have" twice and "cms" instead of "cmd"

Answer (score 0):

After some tests and research on the net, I solved the various problems I had on Squirrel:

1) Installation by clicking directly on the . jar does not install everything, so it does not work
2) My new PC came with javaJDK for developers installed, but not the runtime version => you need to download and install it before (version 8 for instance).
3) From there, it is possible to install Squirrel with a DOS command window, cmd, then java -jar 
4) Do not reinstall in a directory already occupied by a previous test installation or a previous version: the objects are not updated if they have the same name (almost all the time => my problem)

So, the problem is solved, the post can be closed.

Thanks everybody.

Loïc